# find the values greater than x in N dimensional Matrix, where x is sum of index

Tags: algorithm, matrix, permutation, combinations

We are given an N dimensional matrix of order [m][m][m]....n times where value position contains the value sum of its index..
For example in 6x6 matrix `A`, value at position `A[3][4]` will be 7.

**We have to find out the total number of counts of elements greater than x.** For 2 dimensional matrix we have following approach:

If we know the one index say `[i][j] {i+j = x}` then we create a diagonal by just doing `[i++][j--]` of `[i--][j++]` with constraint that `i` and `j` are always in range of `0` to `m.`
For example in two dimensional matrix A[6][6] for value A[3][4] (x = 7), diagonal can be created via:

```
A[1][6] -> A[2][5] -> A[3][4] -> A[4][3] -> A[5][2] -> A[6][2]
```

**Here we have converted our problem into another problem which is count the element below the diagonal including the diagonal.**
We can easily count in `O(m)` complexity instead spending `O(m^2)` where `2` is order of matrix.
But if we consider N dimensional matrix, how we will do it, because in N dimensional matrix if we know the index of that location,
where sum of index is `x` say `A[i1][i2][i3][i4]....[in]` times.
Then there may be multiple diagonal which satisfy that condition, say by doing `i1--` we can increment any of `{i2, i3, i4....in}`

So, above  used approach for 2 dimensional matrix become useless here... because there is only two variable quantity i1 and i2 is present.
Please help me to find solution

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly, but it seems like you are asking this: given x, n (number of dimensions) and N, find in how many ways you can sum up n integers between 0 and N to get some value greater than x.

Answer (score 1):

For 2D: count of the elements below diagonal is [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

For 3D: count of the elements below diagonal plane is [tetrahedral number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number)

Note that Kth tetrahedral number is the sum of the first K triangular numbers.

For nD: *n-simplexial* (I don't know exact english term) number (is sum of first (n-1)-simplexial numbers).

The value of Kth n-simplexial is

```
 S(k, n) = k * (k+1) * (k+2).. (k + n - 1) / n! = BinomialCoefficient(k+n-1, n)
```

**Edit:** this method works "as is" for limited values of X below main anti-diagonal (hyper)plane.

**Generating function approach**:
Let's we have polynom

A(s)=1+s+s^2+s^3+..+s^m

then it's nth power
B(s) = A<sup>n</sup>(s) has important property: coefficient of kth power of s is the number of ways to compose k from n summands. So the sum of nth to kth coefficients gives us the count of the elements below kth diagonal

Answer (score 0):

For a 2-dimensional matrix, you converted the problem into another problem, which is `count the elements below the diagonal including the diagonal`.

Try and visualize it for a 3-d matrix. In case of a 3-dimensional matrix, the problem will be reduced to another problem, which is to `count the elements below the diagonal plane including the diagonal`